# Can Findings of Facts and Conclusion of Law be corrected

Tags: texas, civil-procedure

When Findings of Facts and Conclusions of Law are signed by the Judge, but they have errors or false statements, can the requester respond and ask for more clarity?  Does it serve a purpose to request?

Comment: In what kind of proceeding?

Comment: It is a Civil-divorce case

Comment: Do you just don't understand the legalese of the judgement or do you have actual errors you can point out?

Comment: I think a bit of both.  There are statements that are facts, but they do not apply to anything really. Ex:  Plaintiff paid a year's lease up front.  That was true. But not with the funds that were in question.

Answer (score 2):

> are signed by the Judge, but they have errors or false statements

In a nut shell, the judicial system works this way: if a judge issues a judgement saying that 2 and 2 make 5, that is *legally* correct until it gets set aside/overturned by a higher court. To get there, you need to follow the procedure — file an appeal, argue that it actually makes 4 and hope that the appeal court agrees.

There is no purpose to "ask for more clarity". Judges say all they wanted to say in the judgment.